# not showing last sub category on left sidebar

Tags: magento2.2.7

[image: menu is okay]

[image: But not showing last sub category on left sidebar]

not showing last sub category on left sidebar.

Comment: Magento default only show  current category   children category and it does not show all  level category at let navigation.

Comment: For this requirement you have to do code